# Libgdx: Move Body away from touch event

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want an object to move away from the position of a touch event.

So far I have the following:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    Vector3 touchPosition = new Vector3();

    camera.unproject(touchPosition.set(screenX, screenY, 0));

    Vector2 directionBody = body.getPosition();

    Vector2 directionTouch = new Vector2(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y); 

    Vector2 direction = directionBody.sub(directionTouch);

    direction.nor();

    float speed = 3;
    body.setLinearVelocity(direction.scl(speed));

    return true;
}
```

Using this code if I press at the right side of the screen the body moves to the left. If press at the left side of the screen the body will go to the right side. Could someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit fuzzy to me, maybe because you are using classes I don't but generally it's simple:

1. First you unproject touch coordinates to screen coordinate system, where your body object is, like you did.
2. Second calculate horizontal and vertical distance between touch place and your body object. Let's say you get dx and dy.
3. If you want constant speed you just have to check are those dx and dy positive or negative and depending on that you set positive or negative speed, i.e.:

   if (dx >0) vx = SPEED_CONSTANT;

   else vx = -SPEED_CONSTANT;

Same goes for vertical speed.

4. If you want your body to accelerate you should use those dx and dy multiplied with some constant. That is, the bigger dx is the higher vertical speed should be. Same goes for vertical speed:

   vx = dx * SPEED_CONSTANT;

   vy = dy * SPEED_SONSTANT;
5. If you want your body to decelerate then you should devide some constant value with those dx and dy, to have opposite effect:

   vx = SPEED_CONSTANT / dx;

   vy = SPEED_CONSTANT / dy;

Something like that. You can set value of that SPEED_CONSTANT by trying some values - tune it up.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll look through it.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally did it.

Code snippet:

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

    Vector3 touchPosition3D = new Vector3();

    //Change touch coordinates to world coordinates
    camera.unproject(touchPosition3D.set(screenX, screenY, 0));

    //Add unit factor to the vector
    touchPosition3D.x = Utility.convertToMeter(touchPosition3D.x);
    touchPosition3D.y = Utility.convertToMeter(touchPosition3D.y);

    Vector3 bodyPosition = new Vector3(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, 0 );

    Vector3 finalVector = new Vector3(bodyPosition.x, bodyPosition.y, 0).sub(touchPosition3D);

    Vector2 direction = new Vector2(finalVector.x, finalVector.y);

    float speed = 3;
    body.setLinearVelocity(direction.scl(speed));

    return true;
}
```

Basically I had to unproject the touchDown coordinates and convert them to the units I'm using in my application.
Then I do a simple Vector operation, subtracting the calcualted touch vector drom the vector of my body.
Finally apply some linear velocity.